# Pre fill info based on previously answered questions

Tags: google-forms, autofill

I want to use Google Forms to collect Contact Info for students.

In the case of families with more than one student at the school, I would like to see if there is a way to use one form for all students in one family. In this case, I would use conditional logic to continue on to the contact info for each student.

I would like to know if there is a way to pre-fill the info for any subsequent students in the family (based on the answers for the first student entered), but still allow the answers to be edited.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: You don't have to Pre fill anything. Instead you can use a single form like [this one](https://forms.gle/62h4NXf7VshT6Y7R9). If you are still interested let me know and I'll show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. As I thought about it, I came to a similar conclusion. I did note that even though I checked 2 children to register, the logic still let me add a third. I am not sure that the first screen would be necessary if it can't be used as part of the logic.

Comment: _"I am not sure that the first screen would be necessary if it can't be used as part of the logic"_. That is only used for the sample form. It will not be in your final form. Since you came to the same conclusion, please create and post the link here of a sample form with all the questions you are going to use so I can help you out. You can also try out my form by submiting a response.